# ASP.NET Api update only not null property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a simple api where I would like to edit the object's data using the PUT method. However, I only upload some properties of this object to the API (because I don't edit all the fields). Is it possible for me to download an object with a given id from the database and update only its properties, which are not empty in the submitted object?

**Questions (Model)**

```
[Key]
public int QuestionId { get; set; }
public string QuestionContent { get; set; }
public string MediaUrl { get; set; }
public string Description{ get; set; }
```

**API method**

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("{id:int}")]
public Questions Edit(int id, [FromQuery]Questions question)
{
 Questions currentQuestion = _context.Questions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionId == id);
}
```

I update object using Postman like this:
[image]

Now, in this case i send request to the method and i got Question id, Questions object with MediaUrl, QuestionContent, and null as Description.

It is possible update selected Question object (selected using passed id) using passing Question property who not null?

Comment: It is convention that PUT should update all fields and replace original version of data. PATCH should be used for partial update. You are looking for JsonPatchDocument https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-web-api/asp-net-core-api-how-to-perform-partial-update-using-http-patch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use automapper and try to ignore the null values like the following

```
CreateMap<Questions, Questions>()
     .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, member) => member != null));
```